# hpux leaves files that start with a # behind after I uninstall a program. Is this normal and how do I delete them?

Tags: package-management, hp-ux

I have tried using `rm -f` on these files, and I am running as root, so I should be able to delete them. So why does this program leave behind these files and how can I remove them.
Here is what the files look like:

`-rwxr-xr-x   1 root       sys        6180112 Apr  2 23:28 ##libprog.so.4.5.1

-rwxr-xr-x   1 root       sys         427384 Apr  2 23:28 ##libprogn.so.1.0.0

-rwxr-xr-x   1 root       sys         578912 Apr  2 23:28 ##libprogcacheipc.so.1.0.0

-rwxr-xr-x   1 root       sys         225976 Apr  2 23:28 ##libvtsmartcache.so.1.0.0

-rwxr-xr-x   1 root       sys        1338920 Apr  2 23:28 ##libprogil.so.1.0.0

-rwxr-xr-x   1 root       sys        6180112 Apr  2 23:28 #libprog4.so.4.5.1`
Here is the error I get when trying to remove a file:
`rm -f /opt/prog/lib/hpux64/##libprog.so.4.5.1 
rm: /opt/prog/lib/hpux64/##libprog.so.4.5.1 not removed.  Text file busy`

Comment: After doing some googling, I found I can use `fuser -fu` on the file to find out who is using the file. root is still using it, but I can't see it when running `ps -ef`. Any ideas why these files are left behind?

Answer (score 1):

Besides `fuser`, another helpful tool for getting information about open files and the processes using them is `lsof`.

As a linux user I don't know much about hpux, but does `ps -ef` on that platform show defunct processes? Is there an option to show hidden processes? Are you running `ps` as root? It sounds like something got borked on your system and perhaps a process died or was killed while it still had disk io calls queued up? Do these files still show as in use after restarting the system?

Comment: yes, `ps -ef` does show defunct processes and there is one on the machine. I am running ps as root. The man page says `ps -e` should show all processes.  Looks like I should talk to the makers of the program to see why the process is going defunct. [This](http://forums11.itrc.hp.com/service/forums/questionanswer.do?threadId=702079&admit=109447626+1302541855906+28353475) was informative. Thanks!

Comment: @user6502: Make sure you read the last posting there. Your problem is not from a defunct process, it's from a live process that's linked with these libraries (they aren't executables, they're shared libraries, so `ps` won't help). `lsof` should tell you what these processes are.